# How can I fix these problems with a BlackBerry PhoneGap project and the simulator?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Based on the instructions [here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20BlackBerry%20WebWorks#CreateaBlackBerryWebWorksProjectinEclipse), I started a PhoneGap project in Eclipse that targets BlackBerry.  However, I'm running into two problems with this project:

1. If the simulator is not open, it will open but the application will not be installed properly.
2. If the simulator is already open, a message will appear with the text: `The emulator is loading, please wait...`, but nothing will happen.

What could be causing this, and how can I get my PhoneGap project working correctly with the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that the problem in java-version

i used java7 - and it cause this problem

i tried java 6 update 25 and it works fine

thanks